# How to plot only section of QPolarChart?

Tags: c++, qt, charts

I am using QPolarChart to display a few points p(distance,angle).

QPolarChart with points

[image]

This chart shows always a full circle, independent of my min/max values.

```
const qreal angularMin = -180;
const qreal angularMax = 180;
angularAxis->setRange(angularMin, angularMax);
```

However, I haven't found a solution to plot/cut only the section from +/-45° and flip it horizontally.
Are there any nice tricks available?

Comment: You could show an edited image of what you want to get at the end.